# RealmRecylerAdapter with RxJava

Tags: android, realm, rx-java

With the following code. I expect:

1. Get all the data from the server side.

2. Insert all the data to Realm

3. Refresh RecycleView with Realm Adapter.

The first time, the data is always empty. Maybe the data is still not ready but subscribe is still invoked? Is there any way to update the view when the data is ready?

```
ApiCall().doOnNext(response -> {
    Realm realm = Realm.getDefaultInstance();
    try {
        realm.beginTransaction();
        realm.insertOrUpdate(response);
        realm.commitTransaction();
    } finally {
        realm.close();
}
}).subscribeOn(Schedulers.io())
  .unsubscribeOn(Schedulers.computation())
  .observeOn(AndroidSchedulers.mainThread())
  .subscribe(new exObserver<List<T>>() {
      @Override
      public void onResponse(List<T> response) {
          updateView()
      }
      @Override
      public void onFailure(exException exception) {
          adapter.notifyChanged();
      }
});
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As EpicPandaForce mentioned, you don't need to notify `RealmRecyclerViewAdapter` when there is a change.

My answer will specifically target your use of RxJava.

`doOnNext()` is a side-effect method.
This means it will be called parallel to your stream, without affecting it.

When your api call returns, the `Action1` in `doOnNext()` and the `Observer` in `subscribe()` will both be triggered at the same time.

This means `updateView()` is called before the Realm transaction finishes.

If you want to update your view after inserting into the DB, your transaction must happen in your stream.

You could use `flatMap()` for this purpose.

Comment: Perfect answer. Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

[`RealmRecyclerViewAdapter`](https://github.com/realm/realm-android-adapters) already observes the provided data set with a `RealmChangeListener`, and calls `adapter.notifyDataSetChanged()` when a change happens in the underlying Realm.

Why are you trying to manually call `adapter.notifyDataSetChanged()`? The [`RealmRecyclerViewAdapter`](https://github.com/realm/realm-android-adapters) was specifically created so that you don't need to do that.

Answer (score 0):

What is your apiCall() method? try using Observable.defer(()-> apicall()) if you're not using Retrofit. This will delay code evaluation until actual value arrive.

Comment: I'm using Retrofit.